# no of permutation for multi class classification in permutation test

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, permutation-test

Suppose I have 2 classifiers for multi class classification (say n classes)and some eval score. I want to do permutation test on it. How can I calculate no. of permutations required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to Philip Good's text *Permutation Tests*, a good rule of thumb is ["between 100 and 1600, depending on the precision that is desired"](https://books.google.com/books?id=pK3hBwAAQBAJ&pg=PR15#v=onepage&q&f=false). See the link for greater elaboration.

If you're interested in a more computationally efficient, but somewhat more complex, solution, you could consider implementing something from Axel Gandy's paper [Sequential Implementation of Monte Carlo Tests with Uniformly Bounded Resampling Risk](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612488.pdf) (or use [his R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simctest/index.html) if you're using R). This method basically guarantees that your stopping rule has only an arbitrarily small probability of falsely coming to the wrong conclusion, while allowing you to compute a small number of permutation tests if it's obvious that the *p*-value lies on one side or the other of the cutoff.